# Getting error while creating tenant using email address of the tenant which has been deleted

Tags: kaa

I had created a tenant with an email but later deleted it,I currently have two tenants with other email addresses.When I am trying to create a new tenant with the email address of earlier deleted tenant error "Email address is already in use" is shown ,there is no tenant with this email or administrator.Kindly guide

Comment: Which version of Kaa do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in 0.10 release.

In addition, we separated the processes of Tenant and Tenant Admin creation.
Please, note that from now on these are two separate entities.
For more information, see [link](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/Tenants-and-applications-management/#managing-tenants).

The newest version of Kaa is coming soon.

Comment: Thanks should I update it now with 0.10 or wait for the more recent version if it's release is very near or will it take some more time ?

Comment: you can download it from official [site](http://www.kaaproject.org/kaa-download/)